# Find out how much memory an iPhone has?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, memory, nsdata

My app takes the NSData of movie objects and sends it over a network. The problem is, if the video is large enough, I'm worried my app will crash because of having so much data in memory. Is there a way to check the limits of the iPhone being used, so I can stop it transferring videos larger than that?

Answer (score 2):

Your application will receive a memory warning when it is using too much memory.  That is your only way of knowing.  A view controller will get its `didReceiveMemoryWarning` method called.  A `UIApplicationDidReceiveMemoryWarningNotification` event will also be raised.

Answer (score 1):

I dont think its right define a limit on the basis of memory available in the device. I would suggest you to upload file from disk. ASIHTTP has provision to stream file from disk. This will solve your memory problem.

Answer (score 0):

Even if you find out the amount of memory available on the current device, the system will start killing apps long before you allocate even a half of that amount. Can’t you simply choose a sensible safe block size and send the video in chunks?

Comment: I've just been considering this option. What would you consider a sensible safe block size? 20mb too much?

Comment: I would go for the smallest size that doesn’t slow down the transfer. Probably start around 1 MB and see how that goes.